# keep the session alive for long request

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, keep-alive, httpsession

Let me explain the background, we have built Java EE the application it is deployed in weblogic server. The application is deployed as ear, this contains 2 wars, UI module war and JAX-RS server war. UI module war sends the request to JAX-RS server war and displays the data in the browser.

Now we request called export data in which user can export the lot data it takes longer time like hours. we would like to have the user logged in when the export request is running.

weblogic 10.3.6

I know we can configure session like

```
<session-config><session-timeout>-1</session-timeout></session-config>
```

Question: How to keep the user session alive for long time running request ?
Update: I am looking for configuration specific to export requests other request should continue have lesser session timeout.

Please let me know if something is not clear ?

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with setting the session timeout, as you suggested?

Comment: ok. I forgot to mention the new session timeout should be specific to export request. other request should have  lesser session timeout.

Comment: There's a major design mistake in your application. JAX-RS is REST. The "S" in REST stands for "Stateless", not "Stateful". In other words, REST is designed to never have need for stateful stuff like the HTTP session. In case you're actually forced to grab the HTTP session inside a JAX-RS service for some unclear technical reason, you're essentially misunderstanding/abusing REST. Perhaps you're another victim of the REST overhype. That said, "J2EE" was upgraded to "Java EE" nearly a decade ago and JAX-RS never existed in J2EE. Please catch up. I already fixed the question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `SessionListener` for that. Just access the session via request object. You could try something like this:

```
// pseudo code
if(request is exportData) {
   request.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(longTime);
}
else {
   // reset to your default value if no long request in progress
}
```

You could put it in your servlet, filter or JAX-RS service as needed.

Just keep in mind that if same user may issue other requests while exporting data, you should detect that and not reset the timeout as these requests will share same session.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to set timeout dynamically for some particular request. You can do it by implementing HttpSessionListener.

In listner's sessionCreated() method, you can set the timeout that you want at runtime like this :

```
public class SessionListnerImpl implements HttpSessionListener{
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event){
        event.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(15*60); //in seconds
    }
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the direct answer but just something to think about.

I am not sure, how good it is to allow sessions running for a very long time e.g. hours in your case. Better would be to trigger a long running job with the user request to export something and give back (quickly) the id of the job to query again. When the user queries again, you either offer the download if the job is finished or give the status of the job.

With long running sessions,what happens if,

1. Users closes the browser or something crashed on user side.
2. There are a big number of users blocking many sessions.